# Redshift - Parameters in IN clause making query recompilation

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a filter with IN clause that would get CustomerIDs from user selection in my query. I am benchmarking the query execution and it seems by changing the no. of parameters in the IN clause in redshift causes the query to be recompiled. The subsequent query run after parameter change in IN clause takes more time than previous run.

```sql
select *  -- some aggregations here
from FactCustomer c 
inner join FactSales s on c.CustomerID = s.CustomerId 
inner join DimDate d on d.DateID = s.DateID
inner join DimTime t on t.TimeID = d.timeID
where d.SalesDate between '01-01-2018' and '12-31-2018'
    and c.CustomerID in ( 1,3,7,9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27 ) 
-- there are over 200 customers and the user can select as much as they want in the filter
-- the customerIDs comes from the user dyamically thru the dashboard
-- if the no. of parameters in customerID change to less or more the subsequent queries take time
```

**My question**

What would be an alternative in Redshift so that I can get customerIds from the user that can be used in my query without using the IN clause?

P.S. Using Temp tables is not an option with my case.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the relevant SQL code?  It is kind of hard to advise you just based on a few sentence description.

Comment: Hey Tim, I've added query reference in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using prepared statements? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html

Comment: Hey Joe, I tested a couple more. I have lots of parameters in IN clause, If i add more than 10 parameters in IN clause and run for same number of parameters say 20 then the query compilation cache isn't used. Any insights?